# Error in arrow symbols.

Tags: fonts, pdf, errors, arrows

My LaTeX installation, and many others on the internet seem to be typesetting arrows with thick bits in them, and it looks like  a hypen or something has been  overlayed over them. Does anyone have a solution---this isn't a problem on inkjets, it all just smudges together but it looks ugly on `PDF` viewers and nice laser printers.

Comment: Are you sure you can see the problem on a laser printer? IMHO this is just a problem with screen rasterization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal. LaTeX uses hypens to draw the lines of the arrows, because it can't really draw arbitrary vector graphics by itself.

The solution (for a few arrows) is to use a vector graphic package like `pstricks` or `tikz`:

For example using TikZ, inside text mode:

```
\tikz[baseline] \draw [->] (0,1ex) -- ++(3em,0);
```

Change the `1ex` value if you want to change the height and the `3em` for the length. You can place material on top of the by added `node[above] {<text>}` just before the closing `;`.

See the manuals of the mentioned packages for more details.

Answer (score 2):

you can draw any arrow with the small package `pict2e`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\begin{document}

foo\vector(3,-2){30}bar\vector(3,-12){30}baz

\end{document}
```